# Firebase ChildAdded firing every time in my iOS App

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a simple iOS app that syncs 1,000 Contacts with my Firebase. `persistenceEnabled` is set to true in my AppDelegate.

In my UITableViewController I observe the ChildAdded event, download the Contacts and this works fine.

The problem is this - the next time I open the app, navigate back to the UITableViewController, the ChildAdded event fires again and loads the 1,000 Contacts.

What I thought would happen is that on subsequent launches the ChildAdded event would not fire since persistenceEnabled is true and no new Children have been added.

Have I misunderstood how Firebase works ?

```
ref.child("contacts").observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { snapshot in

    if let json = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary {

        for key in json.keyEnumerator() {
            if let dict = json.valueForKey(key as! String) as? NSDictionary {
                let contact = Contact(data: dict)
                contacts.append(contact)
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: check if this code is being called either from viewWillAppear or from viewDidAppear. if so then it will be observing every time you navigate back to this controller.

Comment: Hi Deepak, it is being called in viewWillAppear, but that's not the issue. I expect it to observe every time I navigate back to the controller but I don't expect it to return 1,000 contacts each time. I would have thought it would only return the 1,000 contacts the first time.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Firebase documentation on `.ChildAdded`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/retrieve-data):

> The FIRDataEventTypeChildAdded event is triggered once **for each existing child** and then again every time a new child is added to the specified path.

Using persistence doesn't make a difference to this behavior. It just ensure that the event will also work in this way if the app is started while you don't have network connectivity.

Comment: Thanks Frank, I suspected that was the case. Is this loading 1,000 contacts into memory? In my scenario I want to have my local cache of contacts which I can then query, like you would in a typical CoreData scenario, and only update this cache when a new Contact is added on the back end. It seems with Firebase that I'm always loading these 1,000 Contacts either from a local cache (persisted) or over the network.

Comment: The Firebase API is an online-first API, which continues to work when your app is offline for a brief to medium length period. For keeping data up to date, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/offline-capabilities#section-prioritizing-the-local-cache

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen how to prevent this situation. like I want to execute .childadded when new child added not for existing nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Since You are registering observeEventType not observeSingleEventType. So register event only once in viewDidLoad. For the first time you will get all the data available in that node. next time onwards it will give you only the new child added. In case if you want to query firebase every time then register observeSingleEventType but again it will return all the data available in that node and will remove observer as it is observeSingleEventType.

Answer (score 0):

use this method :
Database.database().reference().child("anything").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in ...

this will fetch data once ..